# Need sample code for De-serialization of untrusted data with myfaces 1.1 against wildfly 10

Tags: java, deserialization, wildfly, myfaces

The Myfaces serialized view state strings are vulnerable hence need some sample code to test De-serialization of untrusted data with myfaces 1.1 against wildfly 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Myfaces Viewstates are indeed vulnerable to Java Deserialization attack, when used in client-side saving mode. [Luca Carettoni](https://fr.slideshare.net/ikkisoft/defending-against-java-deserialization-vulnerabilities/) exploited and reported the flaw in Sun Java Web Console, back in 2008. Sun then decided to use server-side saving for view states.

If you can afford to use server-side saving mode, use the following context parameter :

```
     <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
     </context-param>
```

If you want to continue using client-side saving for view states, make sure you encrypt and decrypt the view states with a strong algorithm, by setting following context-parameters, as described in [myfaces wiki](https://wiki.apache.org/myfaces/Secure_Your_Application).